# What is the best way to integrate Highcharts with Curljs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, amd, curljs

***Background***

I am looking for an alternative to the current technique I use to load highcharts.js with my curljs modules.  At present I am loading the required libraries in this fashion:

```
define("Test", ["jquery",
    "js!https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts",
    "js!https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more",
    "js!https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting"],

function ($, hchart, hchartmore, hchartexp) {
    var testFunc = function () {
        return {
            markup: function () {
                $("#mixer").html("did it");
            },
            chartIt: function () {
                window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

               // do the highchart configs});
    };


    return testFunc;
});
```

This currently works, and you can reference my [jsfiddle demoing my current solution](http://jsfiddle.net/dhrobbins/48jwf0b4/1/).

I attempted to shim Highchart using **js!** plugin and create a curl config object as specified by the curl documentation:

```
curl = {
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
        "hchart": "js!https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts",
        "hchartmore":"js!https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more",
        "hchartmore":"js!https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting"}
};
```

but I receive the "define() is missing or duplicated" error when curl attempts to read through the highchart.js file.

***My question then is my solution an appropriate, one, even though it works?  Are there alternatives?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using curl.js's legacy loader.  It's great for global scripts, such as highcharts.

```
var hchartBase = "https://code.highcharts.com/";
var hchartCfg = {
    loader: "curl/loader/legacy",
    exports: "Highcharts"
};
curl.config({
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
        "curl": "your/path/to/curl/curl.js",
        "jquery": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js",
        "hchart": { location: hchartBase + "highcharts", config: hchartCfg },
        "hchartmore": { location: hchartBase + "highcharts-more", config: hchartCfg },
        "hchartexp": { location: hchartBase + "modules/exporting", config: hchartCfg }
    }
});
```

Note that I included a path to curl.  This is needed for curl to find the legacy loader.

Normally, you wouldn't use the same legacy config for all three libs, but since I couldn't tell if the highcharts-more and exporting libs don't declare any useful globals that curl could export on your behalf, I just used the same config for all three.

More info is here: https://github.com/cujojs/curl/tree/master/src/curl/loader

Comment: Awesome - I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks for helping out on this.  I ended up downloading the kitchen sink version or curl to make this work.  Not sure if that was the final catalyst as I was doing a lot fumbling in the dark with this issue.